# Query a Subquery

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have to display the Rank of a user for which I plan to use the Rank() function in SQL Server. The Sql query to get the rank is as follows

```
select a.user_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.quant_points) DESC) AS QRANK,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.verbal_points) DESC) AS VRANK,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.dilr_points) DESC) AS DRANK,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.quant_points+a.verbal_points+a.dilr_points) DESC) AS ORANK
 from users a
```

However, I only want to get the rank of a particular user. If I add a where clause (where user_id = @user_id) to the above then all the Ranks are shown as 1.

So essentially, I have to query the above resultset treating it as a table. I was thinking of creating a temporary table but felt there might be better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a CTE, and pulling your single user out?

```
;with  UserRank AS
( 
    SELECT a.user_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.quant_points) DESC) AS QRANK,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.verbal_points) DESC) AS VRANK,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.dilr_points) DESC) AS DRANK,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (a.quant_points+a.verbal_points+a.dilr_points) DESC) AS ORANK
   FROM Users a
 )

 SELECT QRANK, VRANK, DRANK, ORANK, user_id
 FROM UserRank WHERE user_id = @foo
```

Comment: thanks.. works perfect..  I had absolutely no idea about CTE's.. Learnt something new today. Yay!